# Batch operation not called

Tags: 7, batch-operations

I am trying to write a Batch import to create nodes based on a uploaded file. The form works and I receive the file, and can read it in my submit callback which should initiate the Batch import. Here is the code:

```
function mymodule_import_submit(&$form, $form_state) {
  $xml = file_get_contents($form_state['values']['xml']->uri);

  $ads = xml2ary($xml);

  $batch = array(
    'title' => t('Importing Content ...'),
    'operations' => array(),
    'init_message' => t('Commencing'),
    'progress_message' => t('Processed @current out of @total.'),
    'error_message' => t('An error occurred during processing'),
    'finished' => 'mymodule_import_finished',
  );

  foreach ($nodes['nodes']['_c']['node'] as $new_node) {
    $batch['operations'][] = array('mymodule_import_create_node', array($new_node['_c'])); 
  }

  batch_set($batch);
}
```

While it seems to know the amount of operations needed (how many need to be created) my callback doesn't seem to get called. Here is its code:

```
function mymodule_import_create_node($new_node) {
  $clean_body = make_safe($new_node['CONTENT_BODY']['_v']);

  $node = new stdClass();
  $node->type = 'article';
  node_object_prepare($node);

  $node->title = substr(strip_tags($clean_body, 0, 20)) . '...';
  $node->body['und'][0]['value'] = $clean_body;
  $node->status = 1;
  $node->field_article_category = array();
  $node->field_article_location = '';
  $node->field_email_address = '';
  $node->uid = 1;

  node_save($node);

  $context['results']['articles_imported']++;
}
```

I put a few dumps at the start of the batch callback and it never exits. Watchdog indicates nothing, and no new nodes appear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Batch operations](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/group/batch/7) page on api.drupal.org, the processing function needs to have `$context` passed by reference.

Thus your import create node function should read `function mymodule_import_create_node($node, &$context)` and that should do it

Edit: [sample code](http://pastebin.com/duTbxpgd)

Answer (score 0):

You have to include node.pages.inc in your function to make node_object_prepare() work.

```
module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
```

Answer (score 0):

This Problem happens when we put our file in different folder like as includes/form_test.inc.In this scenario batch function can't call.So to handle this we put 'file' => 'path_to_file_containing_myfunctions' in our submit function.

```
$batch = array(
  'title' => t('Custom File uploader'),
  'operations' => array(
    array('test_feeds_import_form_batch', array($uri)),
  ),
  'progress_message' => t('Uploading Multiple Products...'),
  'error_message' => t('Error!'),
  'finished' => 'test_feeds_import_form_batch_finish',
  'file' => drupal_get_path('module', 'test') . '/includes/test_form.inc',
);

batch_set($batch);
batch_process('admin/import-data'); //Work like as drupal goto
```